# Are objects created as instance variables automatically ref counted?

Tags: visual-c++, reference, windows-runtime, c++-cx

One of the instance variables in my class is an object of another ref class. As far as I can tell, this works fine but I'm afraid that without explicitly calling `ref new Foo(...)`, reference counting won't be initialized properly. Am I right to be concerned, or am I in the clear?

**Example Code**

```
 ref class Foo {
     public:
         Foo();
         virtual ~Foo();
 }

 ref class Bar {
     public:
         Bar();
         virtual ~Bar();

         Foo _myNewFoo;
 }
```

Does _myNewFoo cause a leak? Or is this fine?

Comment: Your tags are not helping. This isn't C++. And it isn't winapi. It's C++/CLI isn't it? You should say so.

Comment: It is C++/CX.  No problems with this code, the ref count for _myNewFoo will be properly initialized.  Bigger question is why you are declaring ref classes that don't look like classes you'd ever need to export to other WinRT languages.  Just use plain C++ classes for your own needs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The Windows terminology confuses me. I'm not sure what winapi actually refers to so I got rid of that tag, but this definitely is C++/Cx or Visual C++ (depending on who you ask).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your answer. If you actually add it as an answer to my question, I'll mark it as resolved. As for your second part -- these are just demo classes. I definitely take full advantage of other WinRT APIs in my real classes.

Comment: Gah, I can't keep up with these language extensions!! I think winapi is for win32. I'd use winrt tag instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant commented on the initial question with a suitable answer:

> It is C++/CX. No problems with this code, the ref count for _myNewFoo
>   will be properly initialized.